# Pillow equivalent of GIMP's Brightness-Contrast dialogue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

How can I adjust the contrast and brightness of an image to match GIMP's `Colours` > `Brightness-Contrast` dialogue?

[image]

A brightness of -110 and a contrast of 127 is what I want achieve.

I found this function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42054155/1705337):

```
def change_contrast(img, level):
    factor = (259 * (level + 255)) / (255 * (259 - level))
    def contrast(c):
        value = 128 + factor * (c - 128)
        return max(0, min(255, value))
    return img.point(contrast)
```

This function reproduces the contrast with the values I want, but I can not find an equivalent for brightness.

I know that the `ImageEnhance` module exists, but that has an unbounded float as a parameter, how do I convert the values I use in gimp to this format? Or is there another solution that I can plug these values into. The [ImageEnhance](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/ImageEnhance.html) docs don't explain how this parameter works.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance

img = Image.open(path)
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Brightness(img)
img = enhancer.enhance(0.2)
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(img)
img = enhancer.enhance(2.0)
```

Comment: Do you know how to make the Brightness and Contrast appear as integers like that? Mine show as small decimal numbers less than 1. Try creating a greyscale gradient from say 25..230 and applying your Brightness and Contrast so you can see how the file and histogram have been affected.

Answer (score 0):

The docs explain:

> This class can be used to control the brightness of an image. An
>   enhancement factor of 0.0 gives a black image. A factor of 1.0 gives
>   the original image.

To match exactly the behaviour in GIMP you can map the range from 0.0 to 1.0 to the GIMP range, e.g. using the 
code found [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Map_range#Python):

```
def maprange( a, b, s):
    (a1, a2), (b1, b2) = a, b
    return  b1 + ((s - a1) * (b2 - b1) / (a2 - a1))
```

Or a good solution that uses the SciPy interpolation functions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1969296/7919597):

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
m = interp1d([gimp_lower, gimp_upper],[0.0, 1.0])
print(m(50))
```